# slack channel_not_found when sending message

Tags: slack, slack-api

My workspace is naveedapex.slack.com and I have created two app "testslack" with bot user named 'ubot' and "user4k" with bot user named '4k'.

I have three member in workspace: 1) naveedjb 2) naveeditv 3) naveedoff

When users (naveeditv and naveedoff) send message to bot '4K' then Events API send event to given url where a message is being sent to channel DAD18LNBF (which is provided by EVENTS API) using `chat.postMessage` Method of Web API but ERROR arose

```
{ 
   ok: false,
   error: 'channel_not_found',
   acceptedScopes: [ 'chat:write:bot' ] } 
}
```

But when naveedjb send message to bot '4k' then HEN EVENTS API send event to given url where a message is being sent to channel DAD18LNBF (which is provided by EVENTS API) using `chat.postMessage` Method of Web API but NO Error is coming and message delivered successfully

Why message is not being sent by first two user?

Answer (score 1):

Are the first two users part of channel **DAD18LNBF** ? If not you need to invite them to the channel first, then only they can send message to that channel.